# PHP and regular expressions, Why isn't this working?

Tags: php, regex

```
if(strlen($_REQUEST['email']) >= 0 && preg_match('^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$', $_REQUEST['email']))
{
    $error = true;
    echo "Please enter a valid Email address";
}

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found in /var/www/team2648/OPIS/register.php on line 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP comes with built-in function for validating some popular data like URLs, emails etc. - it's called [`filter_var()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/pl/function.filter-var.php).

```
if ($_REQUEST['email'] && filter_var($_REQUEST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // This makes your code much cleaner!
}
```

Comment: If that uses the RFC e-mail formatting rules, that's awesome.  Not sure though: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43402

Comment: IIRC now it does, however I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thank You. Thats Much Better, than RegEx which I haven't taken the time to understand.    

So thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You forgot [the delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Add them.

Also note that you regex ignores some perfectly valid addresses (such as `foo@example.museum`)

Answer (score 3):

preg_match requires opening and closing delimiters like perl.  You want to include, say, a slash at the beginning and ending of the regex string like

```
'/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/'
```